# Waveform Analysis in C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, analysis, waveform

I am working on a research project that involves waveform analysis of bird calls.  Essentially what needs to happen is we will identify 'baseline' bird call audio files that represent specific types of calls, and then compare our collected samples against those baseline files to determine if it is a match to a specific type of call.  Since members of our team are doing this manually, it is incredibly time-consuming.  I think we can automate the process, but I'm not sure the best place to start.  I have seen some articles discussing FFT, looked at NI Measurement Studio (pretty expensive for the Enterprise Version), and a few other threads, but nothing seems to jump out at me as a viable solution.

Has anyone done anything like this in C#?  Is there a built-in library in .NET for waveform analysis?  Am I stumbling into acoustic fingerprinting with this idea?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries offering exactly what you are after. Perhaps a maths library with the necessary features is sufficient? If so I have used the FFT functionalities of [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/) quite successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting with Matlab as a platform, and looking first into algorithms for speech recognition using cepstra. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum) Read up the literature, and then experiment with existing Matlab tools for speech recognition on your bird calls.